# Using a dependency with an 'export' statement breaks at Electron app startup

Tags: javascript, webpack, electron, babeljs

I'm trying to use [electron-webpack](https://webpack.electron.build/) to build an electron app with [atlaskit](https://atlaskit.atlassian.com/).

I've setup the smallest possible repo to reproduce the issue: [fstephany/bug-report-electron-webpack](https://github.com/fstephany/bug-report-electron-webpack).

Here's my [package.json](https://github.com/fstephany/bug-report-electron-webpack/blob/master/package.json):

```
{
  "name": "electron-webpack-quick-start",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "esm": "auto",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "electron-webpack dev",
    "compile": "electron-webpack",
    "dist": "yarn compile && electron-builder",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.12",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "@atlaskit/navigation-next": "6.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "5.0.4",
    "electron-builder": "^20.44.4",
    "electron-webpack": "^2.7.1",
    "webpack": "~4.35.0"
  } 
}
```

And my [`src/renderer/index.js`](https://github.com/fstephany/bug-report-electron-webpack/blob/master/src/renderer/index.js) which simply loads the external dependency:

```
import { LayoutManager } from "@atlaskit/navigation-next";

let app = document.getElementById("app");
let layoutManager = LayoutManager;
console.log(app);
console.log(layoutManager);
```

When I run the app with `$ yarn dev`. I get an error in the web console from the Electron window:

```
Uncaught /home/fstephany/Code/Play/new-electron-webpack-project/node_modules/@atlaskit/navigation-next/index.js:2
export { default as ContainerHeader } from './components/presentational/ContainerHeader';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at new Script (vm.js:85:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:266:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:314:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:820:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:677:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:609:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:601:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:715:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
```

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token export` makes me think that something is missing from the Babel transpiling. Especially when the [release note](https://atlaskit.atlassian.com/packages/core/navigation-next/changelog) of @atlaskit/navigation-next version 5.0.0 explicitly mentions:

> Drop ES5 from all the flow modules
>
> Dropping CJS support in all @atlaskit packages
>
> As a breaking change, all @atlaskit packages will be dropping cjs
>   distributions and will only distribute esm. This means all distributed
>   code will be transpiled, but will still contain import and export
>   declarations.

Any idea on how to fix this? I've tried different babel config but I feel like turning in circle...

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by puttin the atlaskit dependency in the whilelistedmodule settings of electron-webpack. See [the commit](https://github.com/fstephany/bug-report-electron-webpack/commit/67f1266e0c97d4125f879422f6606176152235d6#diff-b9cfc7f2cdf78a7f4b91a753d10865a2R12) for context.

```
"electronWebpack": {
  "whiteListedModules": ["@atlaskit/navigation-next"]
},
```